# Is it Possible to Preload MapTiles onto OSMdroid MapViewTile Cache

Tags: android, osmdroid

I'm planning to load complete maptile cache of a particular zoom level to OSMdroid mapview, so that I get smooth performance rendering of the Bitmaps. Is this possible? Or If I'd to ask differently how would I dump particular mapTile cache loaded on to LRUMapTileCache in OSMdroid?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this thread: [Pre fetch map data](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/osmdroid/u0SXXzqHg4U).